# Support single string and array as one parameter

Tags: python, string, parameters, polymorphism, typing

I [extended a method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10029) with an additional string parameter (average):

```
def classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, target_names=None,
                          sample_weight=None, digits=2, average='weighted'):
```

So the normal usage would be something like:

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
```

Coming from a review on [Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10029#discussion_r148928176), the reviewer suggested to support multiple values as well: `average=['micro', 'weighted', 'macro']`

What would be an appropriate way to solve this in Python? I know that the parameter can have any type. But how to handle a potential call with a list of strings? And what would be the type of the parameter? `Union[str, List[str]]`?

Currently I only expect a string, which is straight forward. But in case I also allow a list of strings, should I check the type first with `type(average)` and then process the values accordingly? Is there an elegant way of transforming the parameter variable into a uniform type, something like `averages=listify(average)`, which takes either a string or a list of strings and always returns a list of strings?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to simply *require* a sequence of strings, and if you only want one option, then it is a sequence with a single element. That being said, you probably just use `if isinstance(arg, str): handle_string_arg() else: try: for x in arg:...`

Comment: having a `listify` function would just push your `isinstance` check somewhere else.

Comment: Also, please do not confuse *list* objects with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from pandas:

```
if level is not None:
        if not isinstance(level, (tuple, list)):
            level = [level]
```

This is code from the method `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index(level=None, drop=False, inplace=False, col_level=0, col_fill='')` where level is expected to be a `int, str, tuple, or list, default None`. This simple code simply makes sure that the parameter is now stored in a list, regardless of how it was given.